# dotnet-spark exception in writing to parquet file

Tags: apache-spark, parquet, .net-spark

I'm just trying out dotnet spark.
I modified the sample program to write the DataFrame contents into a parquet file.
However I am getting an exception which does not seem to have a helpful info.
May I know what may be causing the exception? Or is there somewhere the exception logs can be more helpful?

> 20/12/09 15:04:32 INFO SQLHadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol: Using output committer class org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputCommitter
> 20/12/09 15:04:32 INFO Executor: Executor killed task 1.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 604), reason: Stage cancelled
>
> [2020-12-09T07:04:32.6029517Z] [HIS2547] [Exception] [JvmBridge] JVM
> method execution failed: Nonstatic method parquet failed for class 22
> when called with 1 arguments ([Index=1, Type=String,
> Value=myparquet1], )    at
> Microsoft.Spark.Interop.Ipc.JvmBridge.CallJavaMethod(Boolean isStatic,
> Object classNameOrJvmObjectReference, String methodName, Object[]
> args) 20/12/09 15:04:32 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.0 in stage
> 6.0 (TID 604, localhost, executor driver): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
>
> 20/12/09 15:04:32 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 6.0, whose
> tasks have all completed, from pool Exception saving to
> parquetSystem.Exception: JVM method execution failed: Nonstatic method
> parquet failed for class 22 when called with 1 arguments ([Index=1,
> Type=String, Value=myparquet1], )    at
> Microsoft.Spark.Interop.Ipc.JvmBridge.CallJavaMethod(Boolean isStatic,
> Object classNameOrJvmObjectReference, String methodName, Object[]
> args)    at
> Microsoft.Spark.Interop.Ipc.JvmBridge.CallJavaMethod(Boolean isStatic,
> Object classNameOrJvmObjectReference, String methodName, Object arg0)
> at
> Microsoft.Spark.Interop.Ipc.JvmBridge.CallNonStaticJavaMethod(JvmObjectReference
> objectId, String methodName, Object arg0)    at
> Microsoft.Spark.Interop.Ipc.JvmObjectReference.Invoke(String
> methodName, Object arg0)    at
> Microsoft.Spark.Sql.DataFrameWriter.Parquet(String path)    at
> MySparkApp.Program.Main(String[] args) in
> C:\Users\Administrator\mySparkApp\Program.cs:line 46

This is my code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //BuildWebHost(args).Run();

        // Create a Spark session
        SparkSession spark = SparkSession
            .Builder()
            .AppName("word_count_sample1")
            .GetOrCreate();

        // Create initial DataFrame
        DataFrame dataFrame = spark.Read().Text(@"C:\Users\Administrator\mySparkApp\input.txt");

        // Count words
        DataFrame words = dataFrame
            .Select(Functions.Split(Functions.Col("value"), " ").Alias("words"))
            .Select(Functions.Explode(Functions.Col("words"))
            .Alias("word"))
            .GroupBy("word")
            .Count()
            .OrderBy(Functions.Col("count").Desc());

        // Show results
        words.Show();

        try
        {
            //words.Write().Mode(SaveMode.Append).Parquet("parquet.wordcount");
            var dataFrameWriter = words.Write();
            dataFrameWriter.Mode(SaveMode.Overwrite); // Append does not work either
            dataFrameWriter.Parquet("myparquet1");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception saving to parquet" + ex.ToString());
        }
        spark.Stop();
   }
```

Basically the code simply creates the folder I specified in my parquet file's path parameter, but the contents are empty.
If I try to read the parquet file previously created by my Scala driver using dotnet Spark, it reads just fine. Only the write from dotnet spark does not work. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: are you running Spark application on YARN or locally?

Comment: @Vijay_Shinde: I am running it locally using spark-submit. Actually I simply followed the tutorial from https://dotnet.microsoft.com/learn/data/spark-tutorial/intro
Plus I added a bit of code to write the Dataframe to a parquet.

Comment: ok. If you are having Spark Application Id, then try this command to get full logs. yarn logs -applicationId <app_id>

Comment: @Vijay_Shinde I am not  using Yarn though...just running it locally with spark-submit

Comment: @remondo are you able to post the full log anywhere?

Comment: @EdElliott I added the full error log at my github Gist: https://gist.github.com/raymond-ong/02bfc425772d6a33799332e2ecb38a95
You can search the Exceptions. The parquet related exception is at line 2036. Thank you!

Comment: The error you are getting is when running a child process, 0x3FFFFECB (hex version of -1073741515) which means dll not found. Do you have spark with Hadoop and winutils or a separate Hadoop installation? Can you run winutils manually to see if you get the same error?